# check that tag is used in template only once

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter, django-tagging

I write a custom tag for using in django templates:
`{% my_custom_tag %}`.

Using django channels it extends some page functionality. But I a worried that users may by accident insert this tag twice to a template, and that can create some issues because channels will deliver the same info twice etc.

Is there any relatively simple way to check that the tag is used in a template only once and raise an error otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maniplate the context, and set a certain key (preferably one that is not used by other applications) to `True`, and raise an exception otherwise. For example:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def my_custom_tag(context):
    if '__some_weird_name__for_my_custom_tag' in context:
        raise Exception('my_custom_tag is already used')
    context['__some_weird_name__for_my_custom_tag'] = True
    # ...
    # do other logic
    pass
```

Of course the condition is that you do not pass content with this name to the context initially.

Furthermore if you would perform multiple `render(..)`s in a view, these will usually have a separate context, but this is probably desired.

Note that the error is raised at *runtime*. We thus do not *proactively* detect templates where this happens, but we will get an error if it happens.

Comment: I like your approach. But I have a question: the same functionality is available in {% extends %} tag in django: when we use it more than once it raises the error.
The way they did it is this (just copy pasted from django source):
https://gist.github.com/chapkovski/5c7c34667882c3a159cfdc0aa515a4a2

Isn't it better?

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski: well this does not guarantee that it occurs more than twice: it guantees that it does not occurs more than once *per file*. That is something different. For example the file can `{% extends otherfile.html %}`, and the `otherfile.html` can contain an extra `{% extends andanotherfile.html %}`. You thus "parse" the Abstract Syntax tree of a file.

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski: see for example here: https://gist.github.com/joar/4f1aa693c9a29c0d1deb

Comment: ah, I see, you are absolutely right. It may also contain {% include %} pointing to a file using {% my_custom_tag %} as well - and you approach also blocks this. Cool, thanks!!